# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js): Error: Cannot find module 'eslint/lib/formatters/stylish'

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli-3, prettier, eslint-loader

npm run serve was working fine, suddenly it started giving the same error. I am not able to understand the root cause of it and why it isn't working. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

To resolve this problem, it is enough to remove plugins of eslint. Therefore, you must remove below line, and again run your project.

`"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.0"`

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem